# Nativescript UI loaded

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am using Angular with Nativescript.

I want to show a loading indicator on a new page until everything is loaded. I am now setting the isLoading property to true in class' constructor and setting it to false when

> .subscribe(res => isLoading = false);

The thing is: the api call is fast, so this barely shows up, but the UI rendering takes a while. Up to 3 seconds on slower devices. The page is a grid (timetable) of 24*20 cells.

How do I set the isLoading property to false after everything is loaded and displayed?

Comment: how about setting it false in ngAfterViewInit https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterViewInit-class.html

Answer (score 1):

With your scenario probably all Angular lifecycles events will be executed before the actual UI component (in  this case the GridLayout) is loaded.
Try using the NativeScript lifecycle evetns e.g. **loaded**

```
<GridLayout (loaded)="onGridLoaded($event)'
</GridLayout>


public onGridLoaded(args: EventData) {
 var grid = args.object;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is closer than anything angular related I tried so far, but this event fires cca. 1 second before the GridLayout gets displayed